# Npm run serve in Docker container

Tags: docker, vue.js, vue-cli

I just learned Docker.

I downloaded the ubuntu 18.04 image file.

`nodejs` and `npm` are installed in the container.

After I installed the required packages, `npm install`.

Use `npm run serve`.

I can't see localhost:8080 on the external network of mac.

I perform a Google search based on the following information.

```
It seems you are running Vue CLI inside a container.
Access the dev server via http://localhost:<your container's external mapped port>/
```

But I see that everyone uses docker file.

Because I just learned docker but don't know much about docker file.

I hope that after entering the container, npm run serve can be accessed externally, what should I do?

```
docker exec -it 858ba945a7386a7b318587ea35d903fb78b5bc6324d3bbc14c2969d7974ea44d /bin/bash
```

Comment: There is too much here to go over. But, you *must* start with a dockerfile. Use that to provision your container. When you run it you must then expose the ports that you want to access from your host. You are fairly far away from being able to use this properly yet.

Comment: Do you want to use containers for development purposes or deployment?

Comment: I'm only in the development stage now, so I want to use the easiest way to achieve it.

Comment: Docker has a [Sample application](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) tutorial that walks through the Dockerfile system (with a Node application, even).  As @SoftwareEngineer says, it's basically a required part of using Docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**

Use directly official `node:<version>` image, not ubuntu or other S.O. image.
Best practice is to fix a version.

Node image contains node, npm and S.O. environment.

**Second**

If you use **Docker Compose**, in `docker-compose.yml` you have to map ports of your *service* (wich contains `node` image) like this:

```
ports:
   - "8080:8080"
```

where the first is what you call from your browser (http://localhost:8080).

(Ignore eventual separate nginx/webserver container).

If you use **Docker** directly you run command with -p option, like this:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 <container>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add port mapping [see docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)

*-p 8080:8080*  Map TCP port 80 in the container to port 8080 on the Docker host.